# Messenger Platform m.me links ref parameter not being sendt

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

Using node.js

If I use the m.me link with the ref parameter:
http://m.me/mytestbot?ref=test

There is no post sendt to my webhook.

But if I use the url given to me inside messenger: https://www.messenger.com/t/randomNumberString/?ref=test

There is a post with my referall parameter.

I have subscribed to the messaging_referrals webhook in the app settings.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I am able to share the template using share_contents. But the button on that template redirects to my bot with some ref parameters. I am not getting any callback on my server when the user click on template button.

Comment: One thing to realize here, which may or may not apply, is that bots don't talk to strangers while in development mode. So if you're in development mode, only developers added to the app can talk to bot.

Comment: This won't work on desktop browsers, only ios and android.